# Redirect to Www - It will not accept that I have to have www on the name

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

As a starting point, I have looked at these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48784263/9310940). It will not make it make 301 from xxxx.com to www.xxxx.com

I have to enter it myself if it is.

I've written it like this.

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
            .AddRedirectToWww()
            .AddRedirect("helllo-word", "Tema/User", 301) 
            ......
```

That's how I work with .net core 2.0

What do I do wrong since that does not automatically switch to www.xxxx.com and not just xxxx.com

Comment: i have take Cloudflare to make this for me.

Comment: hmm, can you provide a bit more of your code to show how `var rewrite` is used?