# How to use {PATH_INFO} in ASP.NET Core rewrite module?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, url-rewriting

I'm trying to move the following IIS rewrite rule into to ASP.NET Core 3.1 Startup. However, when I do so, I'm getting "System.FormatException: 'Unrecognized parameter type: 'PATH_INFO', terminated at string index: '10' exception. According to [Gitub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6006), PATH_INFO is not supported yet. Is there a way I can get this working without PATH_INFO?
IIS rewrite rule:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CamelCaseFormatRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/InstructionManual/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost$" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="InstructionManual" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I've put this into an XML file in root of my app and call it in Startup like this:

app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, "redirectRule.config"));

This rule checks if the request has a camel case virtual directory name (i.e. InstructionManual). If not, reconstruct the URL to the correct format and redirect.

This rule work fine when I use IIS module. Here are some examples:

```
http://localhost/InstructionManual/?id=54 --> http://localhost/InstructionManual/?id=54
http://localhost/instructionmanual/?id=54 --> http://localhost/InstructionManual/?id=54
http://localhost/insTructionManuaL/?id=54 --> http://localhost/InstructionManual/?id=54
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like I've solved my own question. I've followed the solution in here: [Redirect Non WWW to WWW using Asp.Net Core Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823413/redirect-non-www-to-www-using-asp-net-core-middleware)

based on that, I've modified my custom rule to:

```
public virtual void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
{
  var req = context.HttpContext.Request;

  var p = req.Path;
  string pathBase = req.PathBase;
  var h = req.Host;

  if (pathBase.Equals("/InstructionManual"))
  {
    context.Result = RuleResult.ContinueRules;
    return;
  } 

  var wwwHost = new HostString($"{req.Host.Value}");
  var newUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(req.Scheme, wwwHost, "/InstructionManual", req.Path, req.QueryString);
  var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
  response.StatusCode = 301;
  response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = newUrl;
  context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
}
```